# Extracting init script from bult-in intrfs into Linux bzImage

Tags: linux, kernel, gentoo, initrd

I have following problem - I damaged my system ([Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org) - by rebuilding using [gcc 4.5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5)) beyond repair. I unmounted /home, copied /etc + other important files and I've started reinstalling system.

However I forgot to copy init script. It is still present in kernel image that I have. How to extract it? Please note that initrd is not a separate file but is in the kernel image.

Comment: I would be grateful for listing the contents as well. However I guess it'll be side effect of getting cpio archive.

Comment: I found http://www.cs.caltech.edu/~weixl/research/fast-mon/scripts/extract-ikconfig but I still fail to get the cpio from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After unpacking by:

```
HDR=`binoffset bzImage 0x1f 0x8b 0x08 0x0`
dd if=bzImage bs=1 skip=$HDR | zcat - > kernel.unpack
```

(binoffset.c is in sources of Linux).

```
strings kernel.unpack | grep 070701
```

Gives the listing of archive. Just after the entry for /init in

```
strings kernel.unpack | less
```

Is the contents of script.

It is not perfect solution but at least it seems to work. Please answer if you know 'correct' way (for binaries) easy (not writing long program) - I'm not marking it as solution.